# Available languages for TTS on Android

Tags: java, android, locale, constants, text-to-speech

I'm trying to check if a certain language is available for TTS using `isLanguageAvailable()`.
The possible return values of the method are below.

LANG_AVAILABLE

LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE

LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE

LANG_MISSING_DATA

LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED

It's easy to understand that I don't have to care about the last two ones by their name. But I'm really confused what the rest of them mean even after reading the explanations [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE).

> **public static final int LANG_AVAILABLE**
>
> Denotes the language is available for the language by the locale, but
>   not the country and variant.
>
> **public static final int LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE**
>
> Denotes the language is available for the language and country
>   specified by the locale, but not the variant.
>
> **public static final int LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE**
>
> Denotes the language is available exactly as specified by the locale.

What does this mean? All threes are available for TTS?

I don't understand the sentence "by the locale, but not the country and variant".

I'm testing TTS with some code like this.

```
for( Locale each : Locale.getAvailableLocales() )
    if( TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE == myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(each)
    && SOME_OTHER_ADDITIONAL_CONDITIONS ) {    
        myTTS.setLanguage(each);
        break;
    }
```

As you can see, I just put one constant LANG_AVAILABLE.

Do I need the other two constants too, just in case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you can see here (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) there is a locale called en (English) and there is also en_GB and en_US, so English is the base locale and GB and US specify the country for the locale. If you look at the three-pararmeter constructor for locale there is also a parameter called variant. I'm guessing that is possible to have something like en_US_southern, and southern would be a variant of American English.

To answer your question, if all you want is to see if the TTS speaks a certain language regardless of country or dialect, you could just check
`myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(each) >= 0` because that will check for all three possible "success" results.